# Trying to redirect user to a different page after email is verified in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get my redirect working after user has confirmed their email.

This page loads as expected, however after the user clicks register, the user gets an email and then clicks a redirect link back into the app. When they click on that link, I want the redirect to check if it's been validated `auth.currentSession` and then redirect them to my next page

```
class RegisterSt extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterSt({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<RegisterSt> {

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _redirect();
}

Future<void> _redirect() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  final session = auth.currentSession;

  if (!mounted) return;

  if (session != null) {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const MyHomePage()));
  }
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("loading actual register page");
    return Scaffold(body: _buildBody(context));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check flutter app lifecycle [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AppLifecycleListener-class.html)
You can define an onStateChange callback who handle states changes then verify email when app is on foreground again.

(Maybe there is an issue with your actual app flow, if the user verify his email with another device without leaving the app) you should consider to add a timer to verify the email each (10 sec ?) or adding a notification to communuicate with the app.